# Pointers assignment before assignning address

Tags: pointers, memory-address

```
chat *c = 4000;
int *i = 4000;
float *f = 4000;
```

I wonder why it doesn't give any error, as i assigned value to pointer and nowhere in the program i have assigned address to pointer variable

I thought that it would rise an error as i assigned value to pointer before giving
address to pointer variable

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between

```
char *c = 40000;
```

and

```
char *c;
*c = 40000;
```

The first one just declares a pointer to a character and sets it to point to address 40000 in memory (which may or may not be valid).

The second one declares a pointer, and then tries to set **the data it's pointing at** to 40000, which is certainly wrong because the pointer itself is uninitialized.